# AutoMapper and interface typed collections

Tags: collections, interface, mapping, automapper, dto

I'm new to AutoMapper. Sorry if this is too simple.

This is my sample domain:

**I have a Basket. It contains a list of Food.
Food is either Banana or Pickle.**

I have DTOs that mirror each class in the domain. The goal: from a BasketDto, map it and its contents to a Basket.

This is code that fails. After the last line I have a Basket, but it's filled with DTOs instead of regular entities :(

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<BasketDto, Basket>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<PickleDto, Pickle>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<BananaDto, Banana>();

        var dto = new BasketDto
                  {
                      Food = new List<IFood>
                             {
                                 new PickleDto { Name = "BigPickle" },
                                 new BananaDto { Name = "SmallBanana" },
                             }
                  };

        var basketFromDto = Mapper.Map<Basket>(dto);
    }
}

// Domain classes and interfaces --------------

interface IFood
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

class Banana : IFood
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Pickle : IFood
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Basket
{
    public IList<IFood> Food { get; set; }
}

// DTOs -------------

class BasketDto
{
    public IList<IFood> Food { get; set; }
}

class PickleDto : IFood
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class BananaDto : IFood
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

What should I do to Map also the Children using Food as a IList? Mappin interfaces and hierarchies is really complex!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that `AutoMapper` doesn't know how you want it converted. All the `Food` items derive from `IFood`, so the mapping its performing is the simplest (and is correct). You can force the appropriate mapping by creating a `TypeConverter` - something like this might work:

```
public class FoodConverter : TypeConverter<IFood, IFood>
{
    protected override IFood ConvertCore(IFood source)
    {
        if (source is PickleDto) return Mapper.Map<Pickle>(source);
        if (source is BananaDto) return Mapper.Map<Banana>(source);
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can be configured in your mapping like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IFood, IFood>().ConvertUsing<FoodConverter>();
```

Personally I would take it a little further have have the DTO food items derive from:

```
interface IFoodDto
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This will make your intention a little clearer to `AutoMapper`.

Finally, dont forget to call `AssertConfigurationIsValid` in your mapping.

Comment: For more information on custom type converters: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters

Answer (score 8):

While @Mightymuke's answer is correct based on the original question, there is something else to be considered. From OOP stand point, interfaces describe behavior, and IFood in the example is not a behavior. Using a base Food class, and the [build-in inheritance mapping in Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance), it's more natural:

```
namespace Stackoverflow
{
    public class Food
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Banana : Food
    {
    }

    public class Pickle : Food
    {
    }

    public class Basket
    {
        public IList<Food> Food { get; set; }
    }

    public class FoodDto
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class BananaDto : FoodDto
    {
    }

    public class PickleDto : FoodDto
    {
    }

    public class BasketDto
    {
        public IList<FoodDto> Food { get; set; }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class InheritanceMappingTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Should_map_inherited_classes()
        {
            //arrange
            var basketDto = new BasketDto
                {
                    Food = new List<FoodDto>
                        {
                            new BananaDto {Name = "banana"},
                            new PickleDto {Name = "pickle"}
                        }
                };

            Mapper.CreateMap<FoodDto, Food>()
                  .Include<BananaDto, Banana>()
                  .Include<PickleDto, Pickle>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<BananaDto, Banana>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<PickleDto, Pickle>();
            Mapper.CreateMap<BasketDto, Basket>();

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            //act
            var basket = Mapper.Map<Basket>(basketDto);

            //assert
            Assert.That(basket.Food[0].GetType() == typeof(Banana));
            Assert.That(basket.Food[0].Name == "banana");
            Assert.That(basket.Food[1].GetType() == typeof(Pickle));
            Assert.That(basket.Food[1].Name == "pickle");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's nicer - do that.